# Desactivar scroll horizontal en dispositivos moviles

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, web

yo de nuevo
Tengo un problema, a la hora de pasar mi web a responsive me deja hacer scroll horizontalmente y necesito desactivarlo. Tengo el css con Overflow: hiden y tambien lo intente aplicandolo al html pero nada funciona. Tambien tengo activo el box-sizing: border-box

Que puedo hacer?

```
*
-moz-box-sizing: border-box
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box
  box-sizing: border-box
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif
  padding: 0
  margin: 0

 body
 overflow-x: hidden

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" id="entireDoc">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="topBar">
      <img src="img/Logo Quicklycar.png" alt="Logo de Quicklycar">
      <div class="texto">
        <ul id="barMenu">
          <li class="barMenu"><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
          <li class="barMenu"><a href="#servicios">Servicios</a></li>
          <li class="barMenu"><a href="#maps">Ubicación</a></li>
          <li class="barMenu"><a href="#contacto" class="cot">Cotización</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bkHeader">
      <img class="bgk" src="img/bkHeader.jpg" alt="Taller de pintura automotriz">
      <img class="flecha" src="img/flecha blanca sin fondo.png" alt="flecha blanca sin fondo">

      <div class="texto">
        <h1>El mejor taller <br>a un precio<br> increible</h1>
        <p>Nos preocupamos por vos y tu bolsillo <br>manteniendo la calidad</p>
      </div>

      <div class="btnCont">
        <a href="#contacto">¡Contáctanos!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Que codigo estas usando ?

Comment: TODO el codigo... en la publicacion... lee [ask]

Comment: ya lo agregue, a lo que te estoy entendiendo era eso

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2460uo9t/ <- eso y ya ?

Comment: En css si, necesitas que adjunte el html?

Comment: Si por que si no, no se puede ver tu error. Debes crear un [mre] de ello.

Comment: ya te agregue el html, espero que me puedas ayudar